# How can i rearrange div order at every reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way of rearanging div order?
More exact how can i get from

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

this

```
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

or any other order at every reload.

Comment: Show what you have tried, and give more specifics (random, set specific new order etc.) I leave the mind reading to those capable of it.

Comment: if i use math.random() isn't a chance to have two divs with same id for example?

Comment: It's not correct to use same id for two elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple like this

```
$("#parent").html($("#parent").children().sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() }));
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/CPQXw/1/

Answer (score 3):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/KfY4u/

```
$("div.container div").sort(function(){
    return Math.random()*10 > 5 ? 1 : -1;
}).each(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.appendTo( $t.parent() );   
});
```

And this works for any number of `div` tags

Answer (score 2):

An other snippet:

http://jsfiddle.net/t8gU7/

```
var $divs = $('#container div');
for(var j, x, i = $divs.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = $divs[--i], $divs[i] = $divs[j], $divs[j] = x);
$('body').append($divs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var ids = [], max = 4, i = 0, rand = 0;

while(i < max){
    do{
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max); 
    } while(ids.indexOf(rand) < 0)
    ids.push(rand);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have an array with the order, like this:
var order = [3, 1, 4, 2];
Now, I will assume that you have a container div for your divs, like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
</div>
```

How you should proceed is this: go through the array from the end to the start, and prepend each div with corresponding id to the 'container' div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var order = [3, 1, 4, 2];

  for(var i=order.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    $('#container').prepend($('#'+order[i]));
  }
});
```

Enjoy!

EDIT: my understanding of the question is how to rearrange the divs not how to generate a new random order! Sorry if I missed the point, but that is what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript ES6 is the best thing to do this task. Implementation is based on provided HTML structure.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
let randomDiv = Array.from(divs).sort(() => {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
document.body.innerHTML = "";
randomDiv.map((x) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div 
    id=${x.id}>${x.textContent}</div>`
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
  <div id="4">4</div>
</body>
```